# Is it natural to say "around when" in questions to ask for an approximate time that somethimg will happen?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, questions

Is it natural to say *around when* in questions to ask for an approximate time that somethimg will happen? For example:

> Person A: **Around when** do you think you'll call?
>
> Person B: I'll call around 5PM.

If it sounds off, would it be more natural to say *around what time* as in the example below?

> **Around what time** are you going to come over?

Comment: I think you are right, but the question could be phrased as the simpler "When do you think you'll call?" The reply can by approximate or specific. "I'll call at around 5pm" or "I'll call at 5pm sharp."

Comment: As Weather Vane says. In informal conversation, many people would omit the **at**; **I'll call around / about 5pm.**